# CSS changes when copying and pasting?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to move code from one Code Pen to another, although when I copy and paste it, it changes. I'm trying to experiment it/change it a little, does anyone have any ideas? It also seems to not copy correctly when moving to my own site.

Original:
https://codepen.io/hayleyt/pen/ZyqBYW

Mine:
https://codepen.io/pen/

CSS:

```
// SASS Variables
$white: #fff;
$navy: #2e2f35;
$navy-dark: #1e1e24;
$navy-light: #494a50;
$grey: #a5a5a4;
$green: #20c270;
$green-dark: #18a960;

// Moves menu to the left/right side of screen
$menu-orientation: right;

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .pushNav {
    width: 75%;
    #{$menu-orientation}: -75%
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .pushNav {
    width: 350px;
    #{$menu-orientation}: -350px;
  }
}

ul.pushNav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.pushNav {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: $navy;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
    hr {
    border: 1px solid #555;
  }
}

 .pushNav ,.pushNav a {
   font-size: 1em;
   font-family: helvetica, sens-serif;
   font-weight: 100;
   color: $white;
   text-decoration: none;
}

.pushNavIsOpen {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.js-topPushNav.isOpen, .pushNav_level.isOpen {
 #{$menu-orientation} : 0;
}

.closeLevel, .openLevel {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.openLevel, .closeLevel, .pushNav a {
  padding: 1em 0;
  display: block;
  text-indent: 20px;
  transition: background 0.4s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    background: $navy-light;
  }
}

.hdg {
    background-color: $navy-dark;
}

.closeLevel, closelevel > i {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: $grey;
}

.burger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  #{$menu-orientation}: 48px;

  i {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}

.screen {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  #{$menu-orientation}: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.pushNavIsOpen .screen {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}


// Font Awesome styles - delete if not using font awesome
.fa {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}

// Delete body and .wrapper styles
body {
  background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/379600/pexels-photo-379600.jpeg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 625px;
  margin: 120px auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: $white;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.4em;

  a {
    color: $green;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  button {
    background-color: $green;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    border: none;

    &:hover {
      background-color: $green-dark;
    }

    a {
      color: $white;
      font-size: 2em;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="pushNav js-topPushNav">
    <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevelTop hdg">
      <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
      Close
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        Home
      </a>
    </li>

    <li><!-- Begin section 1 -->
      <div class="openLevel js-openLevel">
        Section 1 
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="pushNav pushNav_level js-pushNavLevel">
        <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevel hdg">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
          Go Back
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="openLevel js-openLevel">
            Section 1.1
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
          </div>
          <ul class="pushNav pushNav_level js-pushNavLevel">
            <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevel hdg">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
              Go Back
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link to page five</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link to page six</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link to page seven</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link to page eight</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link to page nine</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="openLevel js-openLevel">
            Secion 1.2
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
          </div>
          <ul class="pushNav pushNav_level js-pushNavLevel">
            <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevel hdg">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
              Go Back
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link to page ten</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link to page eleven</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link to page twelve</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link to page thirteen</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link to page three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link to page four</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li><!-- End section 1 -->

    <li>
      <div class="openLevel js-openLevel">
        Section 2 
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="pushNav pushNav_level js-pushNavLevel">
        <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevel hdg">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
          Go Back
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link to page fourteen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link to page fifteen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link to page sixteen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link to page seventeen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link to page eighteen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link to page nineteen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <hr/>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link to page one</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link to page two</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="burger js-menuToggle">
    <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i>
  </div>

  <h1>Multi-Level Hamburger Push Menu</h1>
  <p>This is a simple multi-level hamburger menu. The only thing jQuery is doing here is adding and removing CSS classes — all animations/ nav hiding/ sliding etc are pure CSS.</p>
  <p><a href="http://fontawesome.io/">Font Awesome</a> icons are used in the menu. You can easily substitute your own icons or omit them altogether.</p>
  <button>
    <a href="https://hayley.cc" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i> Hayley.cc</a>
  </button>
</div>

<span class="screen"></span>
```

jQuery:

```
var $menuTrigger = $('.js-menuToggle');
var $topNav = $('.js-topPushNav');
var $openLevel = $('.js-openLevel');
var $closeLevel = $('.js-closeLevel');
var $closeLevelTop = $('.js-closeLevelTop');
var $navLevel = $('.js-pushNavLevel');

function openPushNav() {
  $topNav.addClass('isOpen');
  $('body').addClass('pushNavIsOpen');
}

function closePushNav() {
  $topNav.removeClass('isOpen');
  $openLevel.siblings().removeClass('isOpen');
  $('body').removeClass('pushNavIsOpen');
}

$menuTrigger.on('click touchstart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($topNav.hasClass('isOpen')) {
    closePushNav();
  } else {
    openPushNav();
  }
});

$openLevel.on('click touchstart', function(){
  $(this).next($navLevel).addClass('isOpen');
});

$closeLevel.on('click touchstart', function(){
  $(this).closest($navLevel).removeClass('isOpen');
});

$closeLevelTop.on('click touchstart', function(){
  closePushNav();
});

$('.screen').click(function() {
    closePushNav();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to modify someone's codepen is to [fork it](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/forks/). You can modify it there onwards. Also, when you are copying the codepen to your own site make sure you have all the relevant html tags and css/js imported in your files.

My guess is that you are trying to use SASS variables which require more configuration steps. To ease your work just switch the view of the CSS in the codepen to "View Compiled CSS" and then copy that into your site.

[image]